# I want to Insert RadioButton Value in SQL Database using Classes

Tags: c#, sql

I created a Class name EmployeeDAta write this code here  and i want to Insert Radiobutton value in SQL Database

```
 public static void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Employee"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

            using (conn)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ADDEMPLOYEE", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.Name;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.Fname;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.Address;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.Email;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.Mobile;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pincode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.Pincode;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VB", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = employee.VB;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ASP", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = employee.ASP;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", SqlDbType.Int).Value = employee.Gender;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: where is the question? you forgot to add one?

Comment: You need a special DataBase to store RadioButtons.

Comment: Use the text value of the radiobutton.

Answer (score 0):

add a parameter to your stored procedure call:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValueOfRadioButtonr", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MyRadioButton.Value;
```

In the stored procedure on the database, make sure you handle the extra parameter.